# UXTheme: Draw Combobox Chevron Without Border

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-themes, uxtheme

I'm trying to draw a custom control that should use the "combobox" theme class.

Using

```
m_hTheme = OpenThemeData(m_hWnd, _T("COMBOBOX"));
auto stateBG = ...; // depends on window state
DrawThemeBackground(m_hTheme, ps.hdc, CP_READONLY, stateBG, &clientRect, nullptr);
```

gives the correct background (read-only-look) without the chevron. But how do I add the chevron?

```
auto stateCV = ...; // depends on window state
DrawThemeBackground(m_hTheme, ps.hdc, CP_DROPDOWNBUTTON, stateCV, &rect, nullptr);
```

draws the chevron correctly, but with its own border and the chevron centered within the `rect`. So if I use the full client rect, I get this:

[image: combobox centered chevron]

If I use a smaller rect so that the chevron is positioned correctly, I get a separated dropdown:

[image: combobox boxed chevron]

How do I get the "normal" look? - i.e like this:

[image]

---

*Bonus Questions:*

Is there any documentation that does a better job than MSDN? It's as sparse as most newer documentation, e.g. just listing "Parts and States", without describing their purpose (which is not always obvious), and whether it's `DrawThemeBackground` or ~`Edge`for a particular item.

Do I still use the good old `DrawFocusRect`for the focus rect?

`GetThemeBackgroundContentRect` calculates the expected rectable for `iPartId=CP_READONLY`, but for `iPartId=CP_CUEBANNER`, it returns the full client rectangle, so the cue text is badly aligned. Is this... normal?

Comment: Have you tried [Create an Owner-Drawn Combo Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-an-owner-drawn-combo-box)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried replacing *CP_DROPDOWNBUTTON* by *CP_DROPDOWNBUTTONRIGHT* ?

Comment: CP_DROPDOWNBUTTONRIGHT has the right aligment, but oesn't have the CP_READONLY style of a drop down lsit.

Comment: CP_DROPDOWNBUTTON does not include  CP_READONLY if I can say, so if CP_DROPDOWNBUTTON has the CP_READONLY style this is because this is specified else where (the theme ?), just do the same for CP_DROPDOWNBUTTONRIGHT

Comment: "Do the same for CP_DROPDOWNBUTTONRIGHT" - this includes a border, and thus gives the second image, looking like a split button

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could use the ClipRect of DrawThemeBackground to cut off the left edge of the drop down button.

```
CRect clip_rect = rect;
clip_rect.DeflateRect(1, 0, 0, 0);
auto stateCV = ...; // depends on window state
DrawThemeBackground(m_hTheme, ps.hdc, CP_DROPDOWNBUTTON, stateCV, &rect, &clip_rect);
```